# How to use host variables in when condition in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I am trying to execute my task only when the host name has the variable `servers=admin`.

I am trying to execute the below playbook but I am facing an error.
I am trying this because it is similar to something which works for me like `inventory_hostname in groups['production']`. I would like to run the task only when the server variable has `admin` in it.

My host file:

```
[production]
host1 servers=admin,server1
host2 servers=server2
host3 servers=admin,server3
host4 servers=server4
host5 servers=server5
host6 servers=admin,server6
```

My task:

```yaml
- name: run cmd
  shell: hostname
  register: op
  when:
    - inventory_hostvars in servers['admin']
```

My task should run only on `host1`, `host3` and `host6`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`servers` is a variable containing a string that you declare on each host. If you run a taks on e.g `host3` it will be equal to `admin,server3`. The conditional you are looking for is

```yaml
when: "'admin' in servers"
# or
when: servers is search('admin')
```

Now, I think you are simply reinventing the wheel since you can achieve this much more easily and clearly with groups as you pointed out yourself. The above solution would make it harder for example to get a list of all servers having `admin` somewhere in the `servers` variable compared to just addressing a group name.

```yaml
my_admin_servers: "{{ groups['prod'] | map('extract', hostvars) | selectattr('servers', 'search', 'admin') | map(attribute='inventory_hostname') | list }}"
```

This is how I would do it:

Your inventory

```ini
[production]
host1
host2
host3
host4
host5
host6

[admin]
host1
host3
host6
```

And your new conditional:

```yaml
when: inventory_hostname in groups['admin']
```